# Style Border in Buttons ControlTemplate with DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate, datatrigger

I have the following Element:

```
<Button Click="btn_Click" Name="aName">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border Name="tmpBorder" Padding="10">
                <TextBlock Text="General" />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding doIt}" Value="someString">
                    <Setter TargetName="tmpBorder" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

My goal is to set the background of the `Border` element in the `ControlTemplate` if `doIt` is set as "someString" in the code behind. `doIt` is a public member of the defined class in the code behind and will be set by the method `btn_Click`.

Executing the method and setting `doIt` works fine, but the Background of the border doesn't change to red. Am I missing something important?

Comment: I removed the forced [tag:wpf] tag from your question's title. Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) why.

Comment: @tg24 Is there a reason why you are not applying directly a style to the border with the data trigger?

Comment: @dymanoid thank you.

Comment: @Daniele Sartori: Can you give me an example for how you aim to do it? I'm new to WPF and sometimes it's really confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
<Button Click="btn_Click" Name="aName">
      <Button.Template>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
               <Border Padding="10" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <TextBlock Text="General" />
               </Border>
               <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding doIt}" Value="someString">
                            <Setter  Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
               </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
           </ControlTemplate>
     </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

**EDIT**: since the first approach didn't work try directly with a style applied to the Border

If you don't set a property like a background in a control template your changes with a trigger won't work

```
<Button Click="btn_Click" Name="aName">
      <Button.Template>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
               <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                       <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                       <Style.Triggers>
                           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding doIt}" Value="someString">
                               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                           </DataTrigger>
                       </Style.Triggers>
                   </Style>
               </ControlTemplate.Resources>
               <Border Padding="10" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Style>
                        <TextBlock Text="General" />
               </Border>
           </ControlTemplate>
     </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me too. Isn't it neccessary to give the setter a TargetName property?

Comment: Try to give the border an x:Name and use target name in the setter

Comment: Like I did in my example code shown above? I tested it with x:Name and with only Name. Both ways doesn't work.

Comment: @tg24 added another solution

Comment: Thanks again. Seems like the real issue behind this was my property in the code behind, but i fixed it now. I have tested your solution as well and it works fine. So I am going to accept it as the solution.